# Unable to access variable that has been declared inside a class, outside of it

Tags: python, class, variables

```
class makequestions(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(makequestions, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("Addquestions.ui", self)
        self.button= self.findChild(QPushButton,"pushButton")
        self.table= self.findChild(QTableWidget,"tableWidget")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.data_collection) 
        self.show()
    def data_collection(self):
        zeze=self.table.item(0,0).text()
        zeon=self.table.item(0,1).text()
        zetw=self.table.item(0,2).text()
        zeth=self.table.item(0,3).text()
        zefo=self.table.item(0,4).text()
        zefi=self.table.item(0,5).text()
        onze=self.table.item(1,0).text()
        onon=self.table.item(1,1).text()
        ontw=self.table.item(1,2).text()
        onth=self.table.item(1,3).text()
        onfo=self.table.item(1,4).text()
        onfi=self.table.item(1,5).text()
        twze=self.table.item(2,0).text()
        twon=self.table.item(2,1).text()
        twtw=self.table.item(2,2).text()
        twth=self.table.item(2,3).text()
        twfo=self.table.item(2,4).text()
        twfi=self.table.item(2,5).text()
        thze=self.table.item(3,0).text()
        thon=self.table.item(3,1).text()
        thtw=self.table.item(3,2).text()
        thth=self.table.item(3,3).text()
        thfo=self.table.item(3,4).text()
        thfi=self.table.item(3,5).text()
        foze=self.table.item(4,0).text()
        foon=self.table.item(4,1).text()
        fotw=self.table.item(4,2).text()
        foth=self.table.item(4,3).text()
        fofo=self.table.item(4,4).text()
        fofi=self.table.item(4,5).text()
        fize=self.table.item(5,0).text()
        fion=self.table.item(5,1).text()
        fitw=self.table.item(5,2).text()
        fith=self.table.item(5,3).text()
        fifo=self.table.item(5,4).text()
        fifi=self.table.item(5,5).text()
        size=self.table.item(6,0).text()
        sion=self.table.item(6,1).text()
        sitw=self.table.item(6,2).text()
        sith=self.table.item(6,3).text()
        sifo=self.table.item(6,4).text()
        sifi=self.table.item(6,5).text()
        seze=self.table.item(7,0).text()
        seon=self.table.item(7,1).text()
        setw=self.table.item(7,2).text()
        seth=self.table.item(7,3).text()
        sefo=self.table.item(7,4).text()
        sefi=self.table.item(7,5).text()
        eize=self.table.item(8,0).text()
        eion=self.table.item(8,1).text()
        eitw=self.table.item(8,2).text()
        eith=self.table.item(8,3).text()
        eifo=self.table.item(8,4).text()
        eifi=self.table.item(8,5).text()
        nize=self.table.item(9,0).text()
        nion=self.table.item(9,1).text()
        nitw=self.table.item(9,2).text()
        nith=self.table.item(9,3).text()
        nifo=self.table.item(9,4).text()
        nifi=self.table.item(9,5).text()
        self.questions = pd.DataFrame({'Question': [zeze,onze ,twze ,thze ,foze ,fize ,size ,seze ,eize ,nize],
        'Option1': [zeon,onon ,twon ,thon ,foon ,fion ,sion ,seon ,eion ,nion],
        'Option2': [zetw,ontw ,twtw ,thtw ,fotw ,fitw ,sitw ,setw ,eitw ,nitw],
        'Option3': [zeth,onth ,twth ,thth ,foth ,fith ,sith ,seth ,eith ,nith],
        'Option4': [zefo,onfo ,twfo ,thfo ,fofo ,fifo ,sifo ,sefo ,eifo ,nifo],
        'Correct Answer': [zefi,onfi ,twfi ,thfi ,fofi ,fifi ,sifi ,sefi ,eifi ,nifi]})
        teacherquestions.close()
        teacherquiz.show()
m = makequestions()
choosefrom=[]
for i in range(1,101):
    choosefrom.append(["t",i])

random_name=random.choice(choosefrom)
frame=m.questions
```

When I run this code I get the error:

> File "c:\Users\santh\OneDrive\Documents\PyQt5\yeah - Copy.py", line 481, in 
> frame=m.questions
> AttributeError: 'makequestions' object has no attribute 'questions'

Comment: were you able to fix your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add/declare property *questions* in your class `__init__` method, smth like:

```
class MakeQuestions(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.questions = None
        super(MakeQuestions, self).__init__()
        ...
```

Comment: i tried doing this, it works but it ends up taking the value of questions as None instead of the value that i assign it later on. :(

Comment: then you should carefully examine what is happening down here - `pd.DataFrame`, - obviously it does not assign as it is expected.